# how to return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` as true/false value

Tags: c#

I want to return true/false for `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, how to do this.

Currently I'm getting below error here,

> cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func< System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>'

```
private Task<HttpResponseMessage> PersistData()
    {
        Trace.TraceError("test");
        return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(true);
    }
```

---

update:

I want to return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` with some empty or whatever, how to do this.

```
private Task<HttpResponseMessage> PersistData()
    {
        Trace.TraceError("test");
        //what to return here?
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this a REST API method? Can you provide a bit more context as that may provide you with a better design and answer.

Comment: Is `PersistData()` a controller method or ultimately returned through an ASP.NET controller method?

Comment: Please don't edit questions so that they invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return true or false for HttpResponseMessage, but you can change your type of return value.

```
private Task<bool> PersistData()
 {
    Trace.TraceError("test");
    return Task.FromResult(true)
 }
```

**updated**
not async

```
private HttpResponseMessage PersistData()
{
    Trace.TraceError("test");
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

async

```
 private Task<HttpResponseMessage> PersistData()
        {
            Trace.TraceError("test");
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }
```

Comment: I can change the return value, but I can't do that. I just need to return some success message, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not return True/False exactly, but you can handle this issue by bottom code.

```
Private Task<HttpResponseMessage> PersistData()
    {

        Trace.TraceError("test");

        return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted));
    }
```

And after that you can check if HttpStatuseCode was "HttpStatuseCode.Accepted" its mean true OR another things. same this,

```
   Private bool Validation()
    {
        var temp = PersistData();

        if (temp.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: You should not return a `new` task, stick to `Task.FromResult` as it will create a completed `Task` with the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the empty string using below code:

```
return Task.FromResult(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Empty));
```

Here `Request.CreateResponse` is extension method which creates `HttpResponseMessage`. You can read the documentation at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessageExtensions_CreateResponse__1_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_System_Net_HttpStatusCode___0_).

You can read about `Task.FromResult` at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8).